Using a CP sat solver, I want to use 2 conditions in an "OnlyEnforceIf" but can't find how
I am using a CP-sat solver by google or tools and I am adding some constraints to my variables.
There is a constraints that should be enforce if 2 bool variables are True. However I can't manage to find how to do it.
I tried using the OnlyEnforceIf method as:
model.Add (RandomIntVar < 100).OnlyEnforcef(firstboolvar and secondboolvar)
but it got me the error : Evaluating a LinearExpr instance as a Boolean is not implemented. I have checked and my variables are booleans.
Do you think of any solution to this problem ?

Ok sorry i found it,
You just have to do:
model.Add (RandomIntVar < 100).OnlyEnforcef(firstboolvar, secondboolvar)

instead of an "and" sorry for the confusion

model.add(...).only_enforce_if(b1, b2)

The and is implicit if you pass multiple enforcement literals.
